# Understanding Jquery SPA Implementation

Tags: jquery, routes, single-page-application, hashchange, popstate

I'm trying to create an SPA website with JQuery. I know how to use `history.pushState` and `$(window).on('popstate')` but i have a few questions. Currently i have a router.js file which handles the popstate event and the navigation links. I place the links in a custom attribute(data-navId="templates/page/page.html") or in href and handling it with
`$(e).preventDefault();`
. User clicks the link and `$('.page-content').load('url', function() {})` and `history.pushstate` are executed.

> 1) Am i forced to include the router.js file containing these
>   functions in every template? I want one html which contains these
>   functions only. The templates should only contain HTML and their
>   corresponding scripts. I managed to accomplished that but if the user
>   refreshes the page the template shows without styling or anything. Is
>   using a hash the answer? Or if the user closes the browser and have
>   the "Restore previous pages" option activated the template will be
>   load with its html only.

In the past i developed SPA pages without hash using only `popstate` and `history.pushState` but i had to include all the html on each file and then calling `$('.page-content').load(url + ' .page-content > *', function() {});` to avoid the refresh bug.

I also know that facebook uses `popstate` for modern browsers and `hashchange` for older perhaps by including Modernizr.js or some custom library. But how the router works without including it in every template?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! I was missing the main code of the router which is to retrieve the current url get the parameters with regex(or any other way) and load the content dynamically. Also i made the mistake of pushing the full path of requested template(page to inject) instead of handling it like a query string or via `mod_rewrite(Apache)`.

**Source (query string): https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/6128301**

To sum up:
1) User clicks link, the following code is executed:

```
$('url').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $('.injection-container').load(url + ' > * ', function() {

      history.pushState({'state': "index?p=" + url}, "Injected Page's Title", "index?p=" + url);

   });

});
```

> `e.preventDefault` = Prevents default link(a href tag) redirect.
>   injection-container = the page you want to load the content to
>
> `url + ' > * '` = the content to get. Asterisk stands for all elements.
>   You can also load the injected page's main content by using: url + ' >
>   .injection-container > * '
>
> Index is the main page which holds all the CSS and JS.
>   You should also create a router.js file which checks the query strings and decides which page will be loaded dynamically. Notice that there is no .html extension on it because i configured my apache using mod_rewrite to clear the extensions. Alternatively, you can replace the extension by getting the url (`window.location.href` ).
>
> The last thing you need is  this code:
>
> `$(window).on('popsate', function() {
>   // PageInjector function like before...
>   })`